# Use textConnection and scan to switch pasted character data to a vector

Tags: r

I want to use `textConnection` and `scan` in **R** to switch 
a pasted character dataset to a character vector as row.names.
My little example is as follows:

```
x = textConnection('
Arcadia
Bryce Canyon
Cuyahoga Valley
Everglades
Grand Canyon
Grand Teton
Great Smoky
Hot Springs
Olympic
Mount Rainier
Rocky Mountain
Shenandoah
Yellowstone
Yosemite
Zion
')
scan(x,character(0))
```

Each line of the dataset represents a place, thus 
it is expected to have a character vector with length 15.
However, `scan(x,character(0))` gives

```
Read 23 items
[1] "Arcadia"     "Bryce"       "Canyon"      "Cuyahoga"    "Valley"
[6] "Everglades"  "Grand"       "Canyon"      "Grand"       "Teton"
[11] "Great"       "Smoky"       "Hot"         "Springs"     "Olympic"
[16] "Mount"       "Rainier"     "Rocky"       "Mountain"    "Shenandoah"
[21] "Yellowstone" "Yosemite"    "Zion"
```

I then tried `scan(x,character(0),seq='\n')`, but it also didn't work! Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input is quoted, we should specify the parameter `sep` (and not **seq**!) if we want `scan` to use 'non white space' as deliminator.
From `?scan`:

> **sep**    by default, scan expects to read ‘white-space’ delimited input fields. Alternatively, sep can be used to specify a character
>   which delimits fields. A field is always delimited by an end-of-line
>   marker unless it is quoted. If specified this should be the empty
>   character string (the default) or NULL or a character string
>   containing just one single-byte character.

```
x = textConnection('
Arcadia
Bryce Canyon
Cuyahoga Valley
Everglades
Grand Canyon
Grand Teton
Great Smoky
Hot Springs
Olympic
Mount Rainier
Rocky Mountain
Shenandoah
Yellowstone
Yosemite
Zion
')


scan(x,character(0), sep="\n")
```

Returns:

> ```
> Read 15 items
>  [1] "Arcadia"         "Bryce Canyon"    "Cuyahoga Valley" "Everglades"     
>  [5] "Grand Canyon"    "Grand Teton"     "Great Smoky"     "Hot Springs"    
>  [9] "Olympic"         "Mount Rainier"   "Rocky Mountain"  "Shenandoah"     
> [13] "Yellowstone"     "Yosemite"        "Zion"
> ```